# How to remove Apple's activation lock in iPad Air

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad Air which someone gave me, and he said that he's forgotten all his Apple ID details and stuff. So I tried my best to try to unlock it (already used the DNS bypass). What I'm trying to ask here is, is there a way to completely remove the activation lock? Maybe by jailbreaking it. My iOS is version 10.1.1

Comment: No way. Replace the NAND flash inside it is your only solution.

Comment: Have you called Apple? Maybe they can offer other ways to unlock the system that your “someone” can help with. One of them is proof of purchase. “Apple ID details and stuff” are recoverable. So one has to be highly suspicious of the legitimacy of this device.